# Using grep to count number of occurrences for each word found in a regex pattern

Tags: grep

I'm using the following to get number of occurrences using `grep` and `wc`.

```
grep -iEo "(red|white|blue)" somefile.txt | wc -l
```

However, this out puts a number. Instead I would want something like:

```
red: 2
white: 1
blue: 0
Total: 3
```

Is something like this achievable with grep?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you have a line with more than one keyword?  Also, is there anything else on those lines?

Comment: You probably want to use `grep`'s `-w` option so that, e.g., `uncoloured` doesn't count as a false match for `red` (and there are thousands of other English words containing the substring "red", most of which have nothing to do with the colour red.  there are also hundreds of words each, at least, containing "blue" or "white".)

Answer (score 11):

Take help from `sort` and `uniq`:

```
grep -iEo "(red|white|blue)" somefile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

- `sort` sorts the output
- `uniq -c` gets the frequency